# invoking a call fom BB code

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to invoke a call from code how can i do it ?

I tried Phone arguements but it did not worked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PhoneArguments phoneArgs;
phoneArgs = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, 
    lbl_Phone_value.getText());
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, phoneArgs);
```

Comment: This code is correct. what error are you getting with this code.